# Do I need MongoDB Atlas if I have Heroku?

Tags: heroku, deployment, cloud, vps, mongodb-atlas

Can someone explain me why we need the Atlas?
If I have Heroku which gives an easier access to cloud (PaaS), then why we need MongoDB Atlas?
Some sources say that we can connect Heroku with Atlas, but why we need that? And can please someone explain me the difference, because it seems I do not understand it completely.

Will be very thankful to everyone. Articles will also be good.

Comment: MongoDB is a data store. Heroku isn't a data store—it runs application code on its platform-as-a-service. If you need to store data, you'll need a data store, which can be MongoDB Atlas, Heroku Postgres, or any number of other things. This is a bit like asking "do I need a hard drive if I have a CPU and memory?"

Comment: Cool note, Chris! I was researching all that time and got some conclusions. So Heroku stores apps on AWS and MongoDB Atlas (the Atlas itself) stores our data on AWS as well. And that means that we need to pay both for Atlas and Heroku (like $57/month for Atlas and $50 for Heroku with standard plan, the free one will not be ok for the app). Is it a good solution? Or maybe are  there cheaper ones if I do not have skills for using vanilla AWS? And is there any extra charges from Heroku for connecting Atlas to Heroku? Sorry for dozen of questions, I just stuck and that's the second day already 

Comment: These things might be a good fit for you, or they might not be. There are cheaper options and more expensive options. There's no way for us to learn enough about your needs here to hold an opinion. That's one of the reasons questions about tools and services to used are explicitly off-topic (see the [help/on-topic]).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heroku is a PAAS where you can deploy your applications. Multiple languages are supported and the development experience is great (deploy from Git or using Docker, plenty of examples and documentation).

Typically your application needs a data store to persist the data, Heroku offers few options (ie Postgres) but no more MongoDB. An alternative is to use Atlas where you can define your MongoDB cluster and databases.

Both Heroku and Atlas have a free-tier so you can run both the application and the database without cost. As your database grows you might need to buy a different [subscription](https://www.mongodb.com/pricing), this applies to Heroku too if you require more resources or for example no downtime (Heroku Free tier sends the Dyno to sleep after 30 min inactivity).

A good article to use Heroku with Atlas is [Detaching from mLab](https://developer.mongodb.com/how-to/use-atlas-on-heroku)